# dyanamic created input box and set value

Tags: jquery, html, json

This is my json data which I get in page.Every time its bring different data and length.

```
 {
       "d":[
          {

             "MenuItem":"AboutUs",
             "NoOfColumn":0,
             "ColumnNo":0,
             "ContentType":1,
             "MenuContent":"testtest",
             "Header":"Header",
             "MenuItemID":2,

          },
          {
             "MenuItem":"AboutUs",
             "NoOfColumn":0,
             "ColumnNo":1,
             "ContentType":1,
             "MenuContent":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdf",
             "Header":"Header",
             "MenuItemID":2,
          }
       ]
    }
```

So I want to create dynamically field and try to bind it.I try:

```
       var contain = data.d;
       var html = "";
       $.each(contain, function(index, item) {
        html += '<input type="text" val=' + item.Header + ' id=txtColumnHeader_' + item.ColumnNo + ' class="Inputbox" />';

       var txtColumnHeader="txtColumnHeader_"item.ColumnNo;
       $('#'+txtColumnHeader).val(item.MenuItem);  //Its not work.Want help here. data.d have value.
    alert(item.MenuItem);
       });
 $('#divEdit').html(html);//Div is in html page its not created dynamically.
```

I also try:

```
$('#'+txtColumnHeader).text(item.MenuItem);
```

But its also not work.But alert gives me a correct value.What is my mistake.Where I am wrong.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var html = "";
$.each(contain, function(index, item) {
    html += '<input type="text" id="txtColumnHeader_' + 
            item.ColumnNo + '" class="Inputbox" value="' + item.MenuItem + '" />';
});
```

`.val()` not necessary, because you're set the value in the time of initialization.

But if you wanna use `.val()` then try:

```
var txtColumnHeader="txtColumnHeader_" + item.ColumnNo;

                                       ^--- you missed this `+` here

$('#'+txtColumnHeader).val(item.MenuItem);
```

Comment: @ShreeKhanal you can keep track of that `id`, after appending the input into dom you can update the value of that field using `.val()` using that `id` like `$('#'+txtColumnHeader).val(item.MenuItem);`.Can you  make a fiddle please?

Comment: Thanks its work.Thanks @thecodeparadox .I am confuse between `val and value`.Thanks a lot.